# Why formula field in not allowed in custom metadata

Tags: lightning-aura-components, formula-field, custom-metadata

I had a requirement where I need to show list of buttons in a record edit form page. These values I am taking from custom metadata record.
Fields in custom metadata records are Market(Logged in user's market like IN,TR,MY), and buttons (Save,validate,cancel etc)

Till now we were using english language only but now there are markets that needs to show button labels as per current logged in user's locale language(not english).

So I have thought that I will create a text formula field with values something like - {Save,$Label.Save}, {Cancel,$Label.Cancel},

The first value will be for communication with JS and the label value for Displaying Button Label

But found that we can not create formula field in custom Metadata. Though I have other alternative solution for the problem, was thinking why formula field type is not allowed in custom metadata?

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer "why" is because it is not [in the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_fields.htm&type=5).

> Custom metadata types support the following custom field types.
>
> - Metadata Relationship
> - Checkbox
> - Date
> - Date and Time
> - Email
> - Number
> - Percent
> - Phone
> - Picklist
> - Text
> - Text Area
> - Text Area (Long)
> - URL

You'll notice other types are missing as well, such as Lookup, Master-Detail, Currency, etc. It's a very basic object that doesn't have a lot of functionality besides its intended use.

The more technical "why" probably comes from either a limitation in the formula engine or how these records are represented internally.